# Casting AnyObject to Dictionary in swift

Tags: dictionary, swift

I'm getting data from iTunes API with AFNetworking and I want to create a Dictionary with the response but I can't do it.

Error: Cannot convert the expression's type "Dictionary " to type "Hashable"

This is my code:

```
func getItunesStore() {

        self.manager.GET( "https://itunes.apple.com/es/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/json",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                var jsonResult: Dictionary = responseObject as Dictionary

            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
            })

    }
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

When you define a `Dictionary` in Swift you have to give key and value types as well. Something like:

```
var jsonResult = responseObject as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

If the cast fails, however, you'll get a runtime error -- you're better off with something like:

```
if let jsonResult = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    // do whatever with jsonResult
}
```

Comment: How do i assign a value from jsonResult to a local String? variable?

Comment: You cannot assign any value to jsonResult since the `let` keyword marks it as immutable. You will have to use a new copied object.

Comment: @Kat In my example, the `let` is part of the declaration, so there's no problem. You're right that you can't subsequently assign any value to it, but that doesn't seem like it would be necessary since you're trying to parse the JSON.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that your solution was incorrect I was just trying to explain to @Sean why they cannot assign anything tho jsonResult within the if let block

Comment: @kat I didn't mean assign jsonResult TO something else, i meant assign a NEW string variable to whatever jsonResult is. how do i do that?

Comment: @Sean allowed: `var something = jsonResult` not allowed: `jsonResult = "some string"`  because jsonResult is a constant.

Comment: @Sean Parsing the particular data you want out of JSON isn't always trivial - read the different questions here on SO about it and ask a new question if you're still having trouble.