# Cast Anyobject to dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I receive a `json` object with this format

```
"type":[{"id":"926"}]
```

I bind it with an `Anyobject` type

```
@NSManaged var type: AnyObject?
```

and I want to cast it to a dictionary

```
if let t = type as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  {
     print(t["id"])
    }
```

but the cast dose not success and the t still always nil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting AnyObject to Dictionary in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142541/casting-anyobject-to-dictionary-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of "type" in your json response is an array of dictionaries, so you should parse it accordingly.

```
if let t = type as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
   if let id = t.first?["id"] as? String {
      print(id)
   }
}
```