# Swift Casting Any Object to Double

Tags: swift

How to cast an `Any` object to a `Double`. I was able to cast it to a string but I can't find anywhere to cast to a `Double`. Either read in zip code as a `Double` or cast zip code after to a `Double`.

```
let zipCode = ((o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Zip__c"))!

//String cast that works
lender.First_Name__c = String(describing: zipCode)
```

Comment: `as`, `as?`, and `as!`.

Comment: Does not work already tried

Comment: In the code you posted, what is the actual value obtained from `fieldValue("Zip__c")`? Is it a String? An `Int`? What?

Comment: let zipCode = (((o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Zip__c")) as! Double )!

Comment: it is a: ANY...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting AnyObject to Dictionary in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142541/casting-anyobject-to-dictionary-in-swift)

Comment: You shouldn't cast Any to AnyObject at all.  Just cast it directly as a Double, if that's what it is.

Comment: @husharoonie You can't just convert any arbitrary object to a double. You have two options: Either you cast (with `as`, `as?`, or `as!`), which ***requires that the underlying object already be of the type you're trying to cast it to***. For example, `let anyObject: AnyObject = MyClass(); let myObject = anyObject as! MyClass`. Otherwise, you have to pass your object trhough an initializer or function that can convert it appropriately.

Comment: I cant cast to double initially because double has no member field value

Comment: @husharoonie You didn't answer my question. What is the actual value you get from `fieldValue("Zip__c")`? `Any` is not the actual value.

Comment: 92565 i get an actual zip code

Comment: Your zip code it is probably a String. Just use it as a String.

Comment: @husharoonie You still haven't answered my question. Is that 92565 a `String`, an `Int`, or something else? You need to know its actual type before you can know how to convert it to a `Double`. BTW - why would you ever want to convert a zip code into a `Double`? A zip code is a label. It's not a number you will ever perform any math with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can use `as` to cast, though you can do this in a few ways.  The safe, Swift way of doing it is with optional binding, like this:

```
if let doubleValue = o as? Double {
     print(doubleValue)
}
```

If you can guarantee it's a Double you can force unwrap it like so:

```
let doubleValue = o as! Double
```